# required (...)+ loop did not match anything at character 'c' Tradingview Error

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading, tradingview-api

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ItrOk.png)

Here in the above code I am getting an error (Error at 5:0) - required (...)+ loop did not match anything at character 'c'

Can anyone help me to solve this?

I did try to check the syntax & indentation of the code, still the problem remains same & I hoping to solve this.

Comment: Please, do not include a screenshot of your code, but actual text, so it's easier to reproduce :) Also, `for i=0 to n` is not python syntax. in python you would write `for i in range(n):`

Comment: Both your `if` statements for buy/sell have the same result so why are they both useful?

Comment: [Please don't post images of code/data/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors). You can *edit* your question and replace the images with properly formatted text. See: [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Your code is a chatGpt's mix of Pine-script and some other syntax. I vote to close this question.